# Glue job security configuration - KMS error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-glue

What should i do to clear this error? I have associated the IAM role of the glue Job to the KMS policy. But it still doesnt work. What else should i do?
I have given full access to KMS and cloudwatch for the IAM role.
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this. I added the key policy for all the resources in cloudwatch and it worked